# actionscript: how to customize the loading animation

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I have a swf published into the web, I noticed that Adobe has provided some basic sort of loading animation, as I can see it when I loading the swf(including the library swf, the overall size exceeds 1M bytes). My question how can I add some text into it, like percentage? Or further more, can I write my own "swf loading progress bar"?

I am using flash builder 4.

Comment: This is different for Flash and Flex. Update your question tags (and don't forget Flex version, 3 and 4 are quite different beasts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick tutorial, although the author builds the preloader component in flash.  If you aren't up to building the preloader in flash I am sure you could either purchase one somewhere like activeden.net or create one from the ProgressBar component.

It seems the key is to use the preloader attribute in the main Application tag like

```
<s:Application preloader=”com.riagora.loader.Preloader”>
```

http://www.riagora.com/2010/08/custom-flex-4-preloader/